# Подключение к чужому репозиторию GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-push

Не могу внести изменения в репозиторий гитa. 
Сам репозиторий успешно клонирован. Но после внесения комита и команды `git push` появляется следующие remote:

> Permission to %Полное имя репозитория% denied to %Мой логин на GitHub%.

SSH ключ был успешно создан и также успешно подключен к моему аккаунта GitHub. 
Такая ошибка возникает как при консольном "пуше", так и при синхронизации в десктопном приложении GiHub.
При это владелец репозитория спокойно вносит различные правки.

Как решается беда?

Если дело в отсутствии прав доступа, то как их выдать (со стороны владельца репозитория)

Comment: [созданием fork-а](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) и (при необходимости) отправкой [pull-request-ов](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

Comment: Т.е. других вариантов нет? Придется всегда создавать форки и отправлять pull запросы? Параллельные ветки тоже не получится создавать, т.к. при добавлении нового branch та же ошибка. @alexanderbarakin

Comment: Попросите владельца внести вас в `Collaborators` (https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/)

Comment: ну, вас же интересуют возможности конекретного сайта (github.com), а не «вообще за жизнь». если «вообще за жизнь», то патчи можно хоть по почте отправлять (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вы пришли в Git с привычками из SVN.

Git — это распределённая система управления версиями. Это означает, что по умолчанию каждый — ПЖ в своём репозитории, но пацак — в чужом. Когда вы клонировали репозиторий, то у вас на компьютере возникла полноценная копия репозитория, в которой вы можете создавать ветки, в которую вы можете вытягивать изменения из чужих репозиториев и так далее. Но вот репозиторий у владельца свой, отдельный, и своими грязными пацакскими ручонками туда лезть не надо. Если владелец решит выдать вам жёлтые штаны и права на доступ к своему репозиторию — тогда уже можете творить что хотите. Но пока КЦ мало.

В целом, картина такая: у владельца есть репозиторий на гитхабе и, скорее всего, как минимум один локальный репозиторий на своём компьютере. С точки зрения Git вам достаточно клонировать его удалённый репозиторий, сделать изменения, пушнуть их свой репозиторий, а потом этими изменениями поделиться с владельцем удобным вам способом. Например, если вы сделаете свой репозиторий публично доступным, то владелец может сделать пулл из вашего репозитория и слить изменения. Или вы можете отправить изменения по почте.

В рамках GitHub всё несколько удобнее, со всякими пулл-реквестами в гуе и прочими фенечками, но чтобы всё работало, нужно соблюдать процедуру. Вы форкаете чужой репозиторий на свой аккаунт, клонируете себе на компьютер, создаёте ветку, делаете изменения, пушаете в локальный репозиторий, пушаете локальную ветку в свой репозиторий на гитхабе, через интерфейс гитхаба создаёте пулл-реквест, владелец видит ваш пулл-реквест, пуляет ваши изменения, а дальше это уже его забота.

Важные моменты:

1. Вы всегда работаете со своими репозиториями, владельцу вы только сообщаете, что у вас есть что-то полезное.
2. Всегда создавайте отдельные ветки под каждый отдельный набор изменений. Пулл-реквесты работают через ветки. Если владелец попросит что-то исправить, то вы можете добавить изменения в ту же ветку в рамках одного пулл-реквеста.
3. Если вы будете активно работать над проектом, и владелец доверит вам самостоятельно вносить изменения в свой репозиторий, то пулл-реквесты станут ненужными. Но если вы не знаете Git, то на это не рассчитывайте.
4. Мелкие тривиальные изменения можно делать в рамках своего удалённого репозитория на гитхабе без создания локального репозитория. Гитхаб позволяет "отредактировать" файл даже в чужом репозитории, но при этом вы всё равно получите форк с веткой на своём аккаунте.

Comment: Объяснение через Кин-дза-дза порадовало. )